# Naming the columns of data frames in a list

Tags: r, list, apply, lapply

I am trying to use the `lapply` function to name data frames in a list.

I have a list, `l`, of 2 data frame, which contain two columns each. I would like to name the columns of the two data frames the same way: for the first column, `"a"` and for the second column `"b"`. I thought the `lapply` function would help me do that; however, it did not work out as expected (maybe I am using it the wrong way). It seems that `lapply` will always produce some output and cannot be used for assignment (at least not the way I use it).

```
l <- list(df1 = as.data.frame(replicate(2, rnorm(5))),
          df2 = as.data.frame(replicate(2, runif(5))))

lapply(l, function(x) colnames(x) <- letters[1:2])

$df1
[1] "a" "b"

$df2
[1] "a" "b"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
l <- list(df1 = as.data.frame(replicate(2, rnorm(5))),
          df2 = as.data.frame(replicate(2, runif(5))))

lapply(l, function(x) {
    colnames(x) <- letters[1:2]
    x
})
```

You have to return the `data.frame` `x`

---

Form @thelatemail's comment, a really elegant solution:

```
lapply(l, setNames, letters[1:2])
```

---

Using `setnames` from the `data.table` package (thanks to Ananda Mahto)

```
library(data.table)
lapply(l, setnames, letters[1:2])
```

Using this approach the `data.frame`s are not copied. Useful for BIG `data.frame`s.

Comment: Perhaps even more elegant would be `setnames` from "data.table" which would modify the names in place (even with `data.frame`s).